# Using the Java Robot class with Selenium and IE

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer

We are running Selenium with IE and Java.  Clicking on a link on the web page opens a new IE page which apparently is not a child page of the IE Driver so I cannot do a driver.switchTo();  Th page is a form with a blank for a file name and an OK button.  Previous developers created a robot class and sent 9 TAB keyPress events to get to the OK button and then a

```
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Now I need to change the value in the filename, so I counted the number of TABS until I got to the file and then do a backspace and type the name of the file like this:

```
                    for (int ic = 0; ic < filePrefix.length(); ic++) {
                            char ch = filePrefix.charAt(ic);
                            int kc = KeyEvent.getExtendedKeyCodeForChar(ch);
                            System.out.println("Sending " + ch + "[" + kc + "]");
                            if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') {
                                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
                            }
                            robot.keyPress(kc);
                            robot.keyRelease(kc);
                            if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') {
                                robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
                            }
                            Thread.sleep(500);
                        }
```

This works on my machine but I believe the first time we ran this it just paused and when I clicked on the web page it asked me whether I wanted to allow the robot to change text.

Problem is, this will be running in Jenkins and no one will be there to answer that question about allowing the robot to access the text.  Furthermore, I understand when running on a Selenium grid, Robot is not very reliable.

So I am wondering, first is there a way to start up IE and allow a robot to read and change text>

Secondly, will that even work on a Selenium Grid (remotely)?

Better still how can we get the IE driver to be able to access this page so I can use the very simple xpaths instead of Robot in the first place (which I believe is not possible)?

Oh and unfortunately for this web site we need IE and cannot use Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: I don't think I'm buying the idea that a browser instance launched by another instance controlled by Selenium isn't accessible. Are you sure you fully tested that? I've never seen that before. You might need a brief wait to make sure the new browser instance is fully loaded before getting access to it. Can you share the site so we can test some things?

Comment: Unfortunately it is inside our company firewall or else I would.  There is no access from the outside.  As for accessing the window, a very knowledgeable person told me the same thing, that you cannot do it.  We have functionality where you take a window snapshot, click on a link and then wait for the new window and switch to it, so it should be waiting until there is a new window and the window is complete.  But I even did a kind of (for String id : driver.getWindowHandles()) after sleeping, and switched to each window, tried to find the elements, and even switched to any frames.  Nothing wor

Comment: ked (sorry, I ran out of characters above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a real simple test to make sure that what you are stating is true. This code uses a test site to wait for a new window to load. You can take this code, add your own URL and locator for the link/button/thing that launches the new window and see if Selenium detects the new window launch.

```
String url = "http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/windows";
driver.navigate().to(url);
int currentWindows = driver.getWindowHandles().size();
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Click Here")).click();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfWindowsToBe(currentWindows + 1));
System.out.println("Found a 2nd window");
```

If it works, you should see `Found a 2nd window` in the console. If it doesn't, you should see a `TimeoutException`.

Comment: I will try that.  I have always wondered.  The window handles get returned in a set which is not necessarily ordered.  If there are many window handles, how do you figure out which is the last one open?  I don't think it is necessarily the last one returned when iterating over a set?

Comment: Correct. The `Set` is not guaranteed to be ordered in Java. You grab the `Set` before you open the new window and then after the window is open find the handle that isn't in the before `Set` and that's the new window.

Comment: Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 30 seconds waiting for number of open windows to be 3

Comment: yes.  Each click on a link opens a new window.  They wait for the window and switch to it.  They tried to wait for this one but never got it, so had to use Robot().  I had to modify it to enter text in a field (had to do with ctrl-v) but IE by default I believe does not allow that.

Comment: They decided to skip this test.